# How to assign CSS to images which have specific extension, height and width?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Right now I am using this code to assign CSS to images which have `.gif` extension.

```
img[src*=".gif"] {
         height: 100%;
         width: 95%;
     }
```

But I want to assign CSS to those images, which have `gif` extension and `160` width and `120` height.

How can I do that?

I tried this, but not working at all.

```
img[src*=".gif"] img[height="120"] img[width="120"]
{
         height: 100%;
         width: 95%;
 }
```

Comment: Rather than using the attribute selector `[src*=".gif"]`, I'd suggest using `[src$=".gif"]`, which will match the end of the value (in this case, the extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space denotes a child selector. This would be the correct syntax for a multiple attribute selector.

```
img[src*=".gif"][height="120"][width="120"]
{
         height: 100%;
         width: 95%;
}
```

### Working Example:

```css
img[src*=".gif"][height="120"][width="120"]
{
         height: 100%;
         width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif" width="120" height="120" />
```

Be sure to specify the correct values for the `width` and `height` attributes. In your question, you mentioned wanting to select an element that has a `width` of `160`.

Comment: Don’t forget to replace `[width="120"]` by `[width="160"]`.